# Could not write feature into OUTPUT using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, streets, indexing, unique-value

I got a shapefile `layerStreetAxis` from these file I run the code below. For the most of cases the script works well, but I found a case where the script stops in `uniqueStreetNamesAxis` and gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.4\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in
> runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 845, in    File "", line 673, in
> runClusteringProcess   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py",
> line 108, in run
> return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py",
> line 189, in runAlgorithm
> ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py",
> line 71, in execute
> results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
> _core.QgsProcessingException: Could not write feature into OUTPUT

Before, we have some problems, but we changed the `é` for `e` in the street name in `layerStreetAxis` and everything was working ok until now. Do you believe that is related with other character?  Or it is another problem?

```
def clipStreetAxisWFS():

    layerFH.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(31370))
    # Buffer FH zone
    outputs['BufferFHExtent'] = processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT':layerFH ,'DISTANCE':50,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':True,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
    # Buffer FH zone for streets
    outputs['Buffer2FHExtent'] = processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT':layerFH ,'DISTANCE':500,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':True,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
    # Clip streets
    outputs['ClipStreetAxis'] = processing.run('native:clip', {'INPUT': outputs['streetAxisWFS'],'OVERLAY': outputs['Buffer2FHExtent'],'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT})['OUTPUT']
    # Snap streets
    outputs['SnapStreetAxis'] = processing.run("qgis:snapgeometries", {'INPUT':outputs['ClipStreetAxis'],'REFERENCE_LAYER':outputs['ClipStreetAxis'],'TOLERANCE':5,'BEHAVIOR':5,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
    # Rename letters
    outputs['RenameStreets'] = processing.run("native:refactorfields", {'INPUT':outputs['SnapStreetAxis'],'FIELDS_MAPPING':[{'expression': '"fid"','length': 0,'name': 'fid','precision': 0,'type': 4},{'expression': '"area_cd"','length': 0,'name': 'area_cd','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': ' replace( "street_name", \'é\',\'e\')','length': 0,'name': 'street_name','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"status"','length': 0,'name': 'status','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"src_name"','length': 0,'name': 'src_name','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"source_fid"','length': 0,'name': 'source_fid','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"feature_code"','length': 0,'name': 'feature_code','precision': 0,'type': 2},{'expression': '"street_type_symb"','length': 0,'name': 'street_type_symb','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"orientation"','length': 0,'name': 'orientation','precision': 0,'type': 2}],'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
    # Fix Geometries
    outputs['layerStreetAxis'] = processing.run("native:fixgeometries", {'INPUT':outputs['RenameStreets'],'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

def checkStreetAxisByNames(layersLoaded):

    idStreetNameStreetAxis = outputs['layerStreetAxis'].fields().indexOf('street_name')
    idStreetNameDP = layerDP.fields().indexOf(fieldNameStreet)
    uniqueStreetNamesAxis = len(outputs['layerStreetAxis'].uniqueValues(idStreetNameStreetAxis))
    uniqueStreetNamesDP = len(layerDP.uniqueValues(idStreetNameDP))
```

Comment: the code you provide is not the cause of the error the statement causing an error is `results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)` not `len(outputs['layerStreetAxis'].uniqueValues(idStreetNameStreetAxis))`. you should present either a more complete code and/or give a data sample with the process you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please also share whole error message from Log Messages Panel. You get the error because of a processing tool that is not included in the script you shared.

Comment: Thanks. I hope is clear now. Because, it is my first time in PyQgis. It seems that even I do not understand where can be the error